# Why doesn't my PC fully power up before toggling power supply?

Tags: power-supply, post

Booting usually fails (works every 20th time or so), as does resuming from stand-by. The fans work but there's no POST beep.

Now I noticed that, if I switch power off and quickly reconnect, my PC will boot or resume happily.

Do you have any explanation for this behaviour?

Answer (score 1):

[Test your power supply](http://www.frys.com/product/6059388?site=sr:SEARCH:MAIN_RSLT_PG) and make sure it is outputting the correct voltage. If that checks out, you may have a motherboard issue (such as blown capacitors) that affect the way the system manages power.